# Difference between Transducer and NFA

Tags: automata, nfa, transducer

Can someone tell me how a Transducer differs from a NFA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Transducers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) have two tapes (input and output). [NFAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) only have one.